# What are the things that the enlightened people know but others don't?

Tags: enlightenment, ignorance, wisdom

Recently, I heard a list of things that the non-enlightened people don't know about reality. *Ex: Some people might think "everything is permenant"*. but I forgot the complete list. So, what are they ?

It is very useful to know those things becuase I can aware about them in day to day life.

Answer (score 2):

the usual sutta about the higher knowledge is mn112
https://suttacentral.net/mn112/en/sujato

you can read bikkhu analayo analysis with the comparisons with paralel suttas here
https://www.buddhismuskunde.uni-hamburg.de/pdf/5-personen/analayo/sixfold-purity.pdf